# Find all values in array that add up to a specified value

Tags: ruby, addition

If you have a target number, and an array of values, how could you find all combinations of  numbers that add up to the target value?

```
target_number = 42
sample_values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]
```

The answer here would be:

```
14 + 28 = 42
13 + 27 = 42
12 + 26 = 42
...
1 + 13 + 28 = 42
2 + 12 + 28 = 42
...
```

I'm sure there is a mathmatical term for this type of search, and likely a ruby library to do it for you.

How can you do this without nested for loops?

```
sample_values.each do | x | 
  sample_values.each do | i | 
    sample_values.each do | j | 
      if x + i + j == target_number
        puts "#{x} + #{i} + #{j} is #{target_number}" 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a [Subset Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem.

Also check out the [Ruby combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) method.

A quick way to do this would be:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]  
arr = []
numOfCombinations = 0

for i in 0..(a.length) do
  a.combination(i).each do |b|
    c = b.reduce(:+)
      if c == target_number
        numOfCombinations += 1
      end
  end
end
```

`note: this is slow with a large number array`

Comment: Thanks, though this doesn't seem to return anything. I'm not sure why. http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/c1dde/2

Comment: @spuder The code as written doesn't return anything; as indicated in the comment, you're expected to increment a counter inside the `if` statement. But it also doesn't work as written, as the `if` compares the target number to an array of numbers, which is always false. It should compare against the sum of the numbers in the array instead.

Comment: Fyi, you don't need to convert the combination to an array. In fact, it's probably faster not to. Also, you forgot to sum it with `.reduce(:+)` before comparing it to the target number.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Thanks, wrote it a little quick.

Answer (score 1):

```
target_number = 42
sample_values = (1..28).to_a

(1..sample_values.length).
  map { |length| sample_values.combination(length).to_a.
    select { |candidate| candidate.reduce(:+) == target_number }
  }.flatten(1)
```

The code iterates over the range of numbers from 1 to the length of `sample_values`, generating all the combinations of each length, then filtering out only combinations that sum to the target_number, then removing one level of nesting from the result.

Note that performing this over the set of numbers from 1 to 28 takes a *long* time. Changing your example to use only the numbers 1 to 20 yields a result in a few seconds:

```
=> [[3, 19, 20], [4, 18, 20], [5, 17, 20], [5, 18, 19], [6, 16, 20], [6, 17, 19], [7, 15, 20], [7, 16, 19], [7, 17, 18], [8, 14, 20], [8, 15, 19], [8, 16, 18], [9, 13, 20], [9, 14, 19], [9, 15, 18], [9, 16, 17], [10, 12, 20], [10, 13, 19], [10, 14, 18], [10, 15, 17], [11, 12, 19], [11, 13, 18], [11, 14, 17], [11, 15, 16], [12, 13, 17], [12, 14, 16], [13, 14, 15], [1, 2, 19, 20], [1, 3, 18, 20], [1, 4, 17, 20], [1, 4, 18, 19], [1, 5, 16, 20], [1, 5, 17, 19], [1, 6, 15, 20], [1, 6, 16, 19], [1, 6, 17, 18], [1, 7, 14, 20], [1, 7, 15, 19], ...
```

Comment: Wow, you are right, going from 20 to 28 does take substantially longer (still hasn't finished). My actual dataset includes 200 array values, this could take months to calculate.

Comment: Yeah, it just finished on my machine. If you want to process this quickly for 200 array values, you'll probably have to take another approach -- I think this brute-force approach is O(n!), which gets expensive very quickly.

Comment: Depending on the actual values you're using (in both your target and samples), you may find that a recursive-descent method performs better. The observation here is that the brute-force method generates lots of candidates whose sum is larger than your target. Once you've found a candidate whose sum matches your target, you can ignore any combinations that have that candidate as a prefix. But this won't save you much if your target value is large, and it won't work at all if your samples contain negative values. Interesting question, though. Thanks for submitting.